# Can I use a function as a return argument in ifelse in "R"

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I'm currently researching a matching-to-sample task in monkeys. I want to evaluate how often a certain stimulus was chosen, regardless of correctness of the choice.

To do so, I have a dataframe `df` with 6288 rows and 6 columns ("Monkey", "Session", "Sample", "Match", "Foil", "Success"), of which only the last three are important now.

The data in `df$Match` and `df$Foil`are the names of the stimuli (string) and `df$Success` is binary.  `df$Match` and `df$Foil` are made up of 65 distinct stimuli names, which I included in a vector `Match.Foil`.

Now I want to count how often a picture (part of the vector `Match.Foil`) is clicked in all 6288 trials. That is, everytime the name is either part of `df$Match` & `df$Success == "1"` OR when `df$Foil` & `df$Success == "0"`.

I tried to build a vector with the number of times clicked for each part of `Match.Foil` like this:

```
Pic.clicked= vector(mode="numeric", length= length(Match.Foil))

for (i in 1:length(Match.Foil)){
    Pic.clicked[i] = ifelse(
           df$Match == Match.Foil[i] & df$Success == "1")|
                (df$Foil== Match.Foil[i] & df$Success == "0"),
           Pic.clicked[i] +1, 
           Pic.clicked[i] +0)
      }
```

So, as you see I wanted to use the functions `Pic.clicked + 1` and `Pic.clicked + 0` as the returns if the statement is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. It does not work and gives me the error:

> In Pic.clicked[i] = ifelse((df$Match == Match.Foil[i] &  ... :
>      number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Does anybody have an idea, how to build an appropriate counter? I thought about using `switch`, but I don't have any experience with that function and it seems not to work like I need it. I also tried running it for 6288 loops, but that produces the same warning.

Comment: We need a little more information; a short reproducible example would be very helpful. Also, it's not at clear what you mean you say you're trying to return a function; `Pic.clicked[i]+1` is not a function, it's an numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sum(), which on a boolean vector makes TRUE count as 1:

```
for (i in 1:length(Match.Foil)) {
    Pic.clicked[i]= sum((Stage4.pics$Match == Match.Foil[i] & Stage4.pics$Success == "1")|
                        (Stage4.pics$Foil== Match.Foil[i] & Stage4.pics$Success == "0"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your input! I didn't come round to answering yet, because I was so busy. I found the solution, the problem wasn't the syntax inside this loop, but that a needed a second loop around this one. If anybody is interested I can post the code. Thanks again!